# Edimax AC1750 Wi-fi Recognition Issue

Tags: wireless, make, realtek-wireless, ndiswrapper

For the last few days, I've been trying to set up a Edimax AC1750 USB Wi-Fi Adapter, with no success. I started with the drivers they give you [here](http://www.edimax.com/edimax/download/download/data/edimax/global/download/for_home/wireless_adapters/wireless_adapters_ac1750_dual-band/ew-7833uac), and found that I got a `make` error:

```
/home/ben/Desktop/EW7833UAC_linux_4.3.21_kernel_3.16-4.4/EW7833UAC_linux_v4.3.21_17997.20160531/os_dep/linux/ioctl_linux.c:14004:5: error: implicit declaration of function ‘is_compat_task’ [-Werror=implicit-function-declaration]
  if(is_compat_task())
     ^
cc1: some warnings being treated as errors
scripts/Makefile.build:289: recipe for target '/home/ben/Desktop/EW7833UAC_linux_4.3.21_kernel_3.16-4.4/EW7833UAC_linux_v4.3.21_17997.20160531/os_dep/linux/ioctl_linux.o' failed
make[2]: *** [/home/ben/Desktop/EW7833UAC_linux_4.3.21_kernel_3.16-4.4/EW7833UAC_linux_v4.3.21_17997.20160531/os_dep/linux/ioctl_linux.o] Error 1
Makefile:1491: recipe for target '_module_/home/ben/Desktop/EW7833UAC_linux_4.3.21_kernel_3.16-4.4/EW7833UAC_linux_v4.3.21_17997.20160531' failed
make[1]: *** [_module_/home/ben/Desktop/EW7833UAC_linux_4.3.21_kernel_3.16-4.4/EW7833UAC_linux_v4.3.21_17997.20160531] Error 2
make[1]: Leaving directory '/usr/src/linux-headers-4.8.0-53-generic'
Makefile:1699: recipe for target 'modules' failed
make: *** [modules] Error 2
```

I figured I could get around this a few ways, so I installed `ndisgtk` and installed the Windows driver for the adapter. Ndisgtk says the device is present when the driver is loaded; this is supported by `lsusb`, which stated there is a device

```
bus 001 Device 008: ID 7392:a833 Edimax Technology Co., Ltd
```

attached to my system. However, the network manager does not recognize that there are any devices capable of getting WiFi, so I'm a bit confused. Suggestions?

Comment: Please notice that the driver file you downloaded specifically says that it's for kernel versions 3.16 to 4.4. You are running the newer kernel version 4.8.  Your device requires the driver rtl8814au: https://wikidevi.com/wiki/Edimax_EW-7833UAC Here are instructions: https://askubuntu.com/questions/965338/need-d-link-dwa-192-usb3-0-driver-for-ubuntu-16-04/965370#965370

Comment: Good point. I tried installing the driver you linked, and it completed successfully; however, although the device is still detected, it is not recognized or used as a wi-fi adapter, and I am unable to use wifi. I also tried https://edimax.freshdesk.com/support/solutions/articles/14000057252-how-to-install-ew-7833uac-adapter-in-linux-running-kernel-higher-than-v4-4 and it also installed successfully, and failed to change anything.

Comment: Did the driver load? `lsmod | grep 8814` Is the wireless blocked by the hardware switch? `rfkill list all` Any clues in the log? `dmesg | grep rtl`

Comment: Afraid the driver didn't load, and the rest of the tests simply didn't return anything either.

Answer (score 0):

This worked for my Edimax

```
sudo apt install git dkms
git clone https://github.com/jeremyb31/rtl8814AU.git
sudo dkms add ./rtl8814AU
sudo dkms install rtl8814AU/1.0
```

Reboot