# What do I do after I have installed a RTL8814AU driver?

Tags: 16.04, networking, drivers, wireless, adapter

I've downloaded this file:
https://github.com/xxNull-lsk/rtl8812AU/blob/a88cb341d021b58397307a144b1af1d9941da5c0/os_dep/linux/usb_intf.c

I then followed the steps they had in README.md:

```
$ make 
$ sudo make install
$ sudo modprobe -a 8812au

$ sudo make -f Makefile.dkms install

$ sudo apt-get install build-essential 
$ sudo apt-get install linux-headers-4.4.0-67-generic
```

I bumped into no errors along the way, however when I plug in my adapter, nothing happens.

Is there another procedure I have to go through?

Thanks

Comment: Please [edit] your question and add output of `lsusb` terminal command.

Comment: And what is your kernel version `uname -a`?

Comment: It is `rtl8814au` chip. You can find drivers for it, but it depends on your kernel version.

Answer (score 0):

You device is `RTL8814AU`. You can install a driver from git.

Connect to internet by another way and run:

```
sudo apt update
sudo apt install git dkms
git clone https://github.com/ScrambledAuroras/rtl8814AU.git
cd rtl8814AU
sudo ./dkms-install.sh
```

Comment: You can do it that way, but it is a very long story to explain step by step.

Comment: You can't install a Linux driver to your Mac. I updated the answer with an offline guide.

Comment: All additional information should be posted TO YOUR QUESTION. This means that you did something wrong. I told that a step-by-step guide will be not so easy. Where did you copy the source of the driver?

Comment: And what did the first command `cd rtl8814AU-driver-4.3.21-alpine` output?

Comment: It is unclear what is your problem. The `dkms-install.sh` file should be there. But the problem is that the script won't work without `git`. You need to clone instead of downloading a zip. So it is more complex. I suggest to find a working dongle and install in online mode.

Comment: Remove the already existing file by `sudo rm -r /usr/src/rtl8814AU-4.3.21`. And it looks like you are trying to install it after a successfull install.

Comment: I've done that. What next?

Comment: Try to install again.

Comment: I tried that just now. Look at my post, under "However I get this result:"

Comment: Maybe the script is wrong. You can install without using the script. There are a lot of dkms guides in the net.

Comment: I've tried a new script and it looks like it downloaded successfully but the adapter is still unusable.